# Read MS Access database via .net without installing drivers

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, .net-core

I am using .net (core 7) to read data from an .accdb Access database. The following code works fine, but only when I have 'Microsoft Access database engine 2016' installed on my local dev environment.

```
    var connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" + path + "/mydb.accdb";
    var queryString = "Select * from People";
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString);
    using OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    command.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var name = reader.SafeGetString(0);
        }
    };
```

I want to run this code on multiple other PCs but ideally don't want to install Microsoft Access database engine 2016 on each one. All PCs will have office already installed.

Is there any way I can read from Access without installing drivers/database engine 2016? I tried copying the ACEODB.dll and setting the connection string as

`var connectionString = "Driver=" + path + "/ACEODBC.dll;Dbq=" + path + "/mydb.accdb";`

but that didn't work.

Comment: You can't use an Access database without having the Access database engine installed. If you want to avoid having to install ACE then use an MDB data file instead, because the Jet database engine is basically part of Windows and will always be installed, in 32-bit form at least. Either way, I'd strongly suggest using OLE DB rather than OBDC.

Comment: If all PCs already have Office then ACE should already be installed, although I'm not 100% sure that that is the case for Microsoft 365. Your app has to have the same bitness as the installed ACE though, so if those machines have 64-bit Office installed then your app will need to be 64-bit in order to use 64-bit ACE. I think that Microsoft 365 always installs 64-bit Office these days. If the bitness of installed ACE may vary then you'll need to build two versions of your app.

Comment: I think you should *really* consider migrating away from access. In my experience access has a huge problems with things like maximum size, performance, random crashes and so on. Using something like SQLite should be better in just about every way.

Comment: ^^ What Jonas says. And if you need a Single-File, No-Setup Document DB that's native to .Net: I've had pleasant experience with LiteDB (not affiliated). Nuget even comes with a micro-ORM built in.

Comment: @JonasH Yeah - the code is trying to read the access db so it can migrate it into a sqlite db. I have 50+ client PCs each with their own access db that I didn't want to manually convert.

Comment: I would use SQL Server instead of SQLLITE.  You can download the SQL Server for free (express) and will work over network.

Comment: _"I have 50+ client PCs each with their own access db that I didn't want to manually convert"_ - Deploy the conversion program on _one_ machine and have it done there? You could copy / send the access dbs via network or use network shares / UNC ... That's what I'd do. Regardless of whther you use SQLite, LocalDB or MS SQL Server ... the latter would be convenient because you wouldn't have to distribute resulting db files to the respective client machines.